# Delete rows when element matches a list

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, delete-row

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Col1 Col2
0.7   AA
0.6   BBB
0.2   RR
0.8   TTT
0.0   SS
```

And another dataset that looks like that

```
List
BBB
RR
TTT
```

I want to remove rows from the first dataset when values from the second column does not match any of the names listed in the second dataset. Final product would look like this:

```
Col1 Col2
0.6   BBB
0.2   RR
0.8   TTT
```

I cannot find any easy way to run this in R. I tried different for and if loops but did not work. Anybody would know an easy solution?

Thank you!

Comment: also you can: `df1[!is.na(match(df1$Col2, df2$List)),]`

Comment: @AP38: Please clarify whether the second dataset is `list` or `data.frame`.

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan sorry about that. The second dataset is a data.frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R Solution:

**Dataset:**

```
df1=read.table(text="Col1 Col2
          0.7   AA
          0.6   BBB
          0.2   RR
          0.8   TTT
          0.0   SS",header=T)
 df2=read.table(text="List
           BBB
           RR
           TTT",header=T)
```

**Code:**

```
df1[df1$Col2 %in% df2$List,]
```

**Output:**

```
  Col1 Col2
2  0.6  BBB
3  0.2   RR
4  0.8  TTT
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works great! Much easier than I thought or tried!

Answer (score 1):

Using data.table:

```
dt <- data.table(Col1 = c(0.7, 0.6, 0.2, 0.8, 0), Col2 = c("AA", "BBB", "RR", "TTT", "SS"))
myList <- list("BBB", "RR", "TTT")

dt[Col2 %in% myList]
```

Gives you:

```
   Col1 Col2
1:  0.6  BBB
2:  0.2   RR
3:  0.8  TTT
```

Comment: Thank you! This works with a datatable but did not with my large dataframe somehow. Solution below worked right away. The key was to add "," in dt[Col2 %in% myList]